# Member undefined when calling function indirectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

```
class Hello{

    constructor(member) {
       this.member = member;

       this.name_function_map = {"print_member" : this.print_member};
    }

    print_member(){
        console.log(this.member);
    }
}

let h = new Hello(2);
h.print_member();
//=> works as expected


h.name_function_map["print_member"]();
//=> why is it h. member undefined
```

the output is:

```
2
undefined
```

can someone please enlighten me, why is calling the member function of Hello through a reference stored in a map any different than calling it directly?

And how may i work around that.

Comment: Make it: h.name_function_map.print_member(h); and then
    print_member(that){
        console.log(that.member);
    }

Comment: Or with Function.prototype.call: `h.name_function_map.print_member.call(h)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute:

```
let h = new Hello(2);
h.print_member();
```

The **this** keyword inside the `print_member` method will be equal to h (the object instance). That is correct. But, when you execute:

```
h.name_function_map["print_member"]();
```

or equally

```
h.name_function_map.print_member();
```

the **this** keyword inside the `print_member` method will be equal to `h.name_function_map`, which is:

```
{"print_member" : this.print_member}
```

Obviously, this object does not have a **member** property, and that's why you are getting undefined.